# Extracting certain XML element values from different parent elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file containing 10's of Mesh nodes each containing Vertex and Face elements. Essentially for each Mesh node I need to create a:

- New list containing all Vertex (vector3 type)
- New list containing all Faces (vector3 type)
- Save mesh ID (string type)

I am confused as to what statements to use for such dynamic information analysis and extraction. Here is some simplified XML code for illustration.

```
<Mesh id="Cube">
  <Vertex position="0.9823, 2.3545, 30.251" />
  <Vertex position="-0.0177, 2.3545, 30.251" />
  <Vertex position="0.9823, 3.3545, 30.251" />
  <Vertex position="-0.0177, 3.3545, 30.251" />
  <Face vertices="0, 2, 3" />
  <Face vertices="0, 3, 1" />
```

```
<Mesh id="Wall">
  <Vertex position="-4.9048, -1.0443, -4.8548" />
  <Vertex position="-5.404, -1.018, -4.8636" />
  <Vertex position="-4.6416, 3.9487, -4.8548" />
  <Vertex position="-5.1409, 3.975, -4.8636" />
  <Face vertices="0, 2, 3" />
  <Face vertices="0, 3, 1" />
```

My current solution returns an "Argument out of range". I am unsure how to convert Vertices list into Vector3 list and how to retrieve the mesh ID in the first place.

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Test.xml");
List<string> Vertices= new List<string>();
int i = 0;

IEnumerable<XElement> de =
    from element in xml.Descendants("Vertex")
    select element;
foreach (XElement element in de)
{
    Vertices[i] = element.Attribute("position").Value;
    i += 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at XSLT?

Comment: Just XML on its own leaves the question too broad. Post the C# code you are attempting.

Comment: There are many questions about deserializing XML into .Net objects.  Your question doesn't indicate what research you have taken or what effort you've done to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is using the list indexer to try to add a new value. You can verify that that doesn't work without worrying about XML at all:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        list[0] = "test"; // Bang: ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    }
}
```

Fortunately, you don't need it at all - your code can be corrected and simplified to:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Test.xml");
List<string> vertices = xml
    .Descendants("Vertex")
    .Select(x => x.Attribute("position").Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: How would I differentiate between vertices that belong to <Wall> and vertices that belong to <Cube> ?

Comment: @Jellyracecar: You haven't shown any `<Wall>` or `<Cube>` elements (they're just the `id` attributes in `Mesh`), so it's hard to give any information. I suggest you ask a new question with appropriate XML, what you've tried etc. If you actually meant the ID, just use `xml.Root.Attribute("id").Value` to find the value of the `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication106
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Mesh> mesh = doc.Descendants("Mesh").Select(x => new Mesh()
            {
                id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                vertexes = x.Elements("Vertex").Select(y => ((string)y.Attribute("position")).Split(new char[] {','}).Select(z => decimal.Parse(z)).ToList()).ToList(),
                faces = x.Elements("Face").Select(y => ((string)y.Attribute("vertices")).Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(z => int.Parse(z)).ToList()).ToList(),

            }).ToList();
        }

    }
    public class Mesh
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<List<decimal>> vertexes { get; set; }
        public List<List<int>> faces { get; set; }


    }


}
```